# TriggerFirstNavigate() calls start() method of ViewModel before Show() method of presenter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a scenario where I have LoginActivity with Fingerprint option.
When the app starts, I want fingerprint dialog to be shown. I start the fingerprint flow from Start() method of LoginViewModel but the activity instance is null since Show() is not yet called from presenter.

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this.

Comment: Are you using MvvmCross 5.x?

Comment: Yes. I'm using mvvmcross 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MvvmCross, The ViewModel lifecycle is agnostic to any platform lifecycle.

If you need to do something when a particular event happens at UI level, you can use the View callbacks that MvxViewModel has. In this particular case, you can use `ViewAppearing` or `ViewAppeared`.

You can read more about this in the [official documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle#view-callbacks).